# How to properly update Grub in Hosted environment

Tags: installation, boot, grub2

I'm hoping to obtain some guidance to properly update Grub on a GoDaddy dedicated server, as my previous attempt has resulted in re-provisioning the server.  If this were a local server, I think I could start the server from the console and make the necessary configuration changes.  Being hosted, I don't have access to the console - or so I believe, so I'm stuck with a server I can no longer access.

To start, I'm using `apt-get upgrade` (as I'm ultimately trying to upgrade from Lucid to Precise).  This then identifies the Grub update..

There are two separate prompts which I'm unsure how to properly proceed:

**1) Grub configuration**
The update asks what I want to do with the config file (/etc/default/grub?).
Should I

1. Keep my existing
2. Replace with package
3. Merge existing with package
4. Other

**2) Installation location**
A second prompt is to install the boot loader.  The guide suggests that if I don't know, I should install it to all locations.
/boot is located on /dev/sda1
/dev/sda3 contains everything else (eg /)

Is /boot the only place it needs to be located, or do I need to identify something in /boot/grub/grub.cfg to identify where it should be installed?

Comment: Don't touch `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file.

Comment: can you post the screenshots of 1 and 2?

Comment: I would say to replace config with package (you get new kernel) it should re-generate grub.cfg anyways, install Grub in MBR and use apt-get dist-upgrade instead of upgrade if you upgrate Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Grub configuration:

First of all, make a backup of `/etc/default/grub` file. This file is used to generate `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` with `update-grub` command. Feel free to keep existing, but i'd reccomend you to merge with package and compare merged with a backup copy. **Do not replace with package. The system can be unbootable.** `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file will be regenerated at the end of update process. So, inspect the final version of `/etc/default/grub`, modify it if needed, run `update-grub` command if modified.

### 2. Installation location:

`/boot` is the only one location GRUB2 places it's files, but it also embed some code into MBR/boot partition. So, if `/boot` located on a separate partition and this partition is marked as bootable - choose `/boot`. If another partition is marked as bootable (`/` for example - choose all locations).

*On UEFI systems GRUB2 places additional files on `/boot/efi`.*